# Make colors in seaborn based on column names

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have a table with three columns: Names, A, B that I use to create a plot with the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="B", y="A")
```

[image]

How can make two different colors for dots based on column names? (i.e. A - red, B - green)

Comment: you have a scatter plot.. for every row, you have 1 corresponding A and B value.. how do you color them differently ?

Comment: @StupidWolf [:)](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_fillstyle_reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

In a `scatterplot`, each point represents a **pair values**  relating two sets of data, in your case `A` and `B`. Therefore, since each point on the graph is a pair, you can't colour different each individual point based on 'A' or 'B'.

What you can do, is set a different colour based on your `Name` column, using `hue` argument.

Below is an example using seaborn's `tips` dataset.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="time")
```

[image]

In your case try something like:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="B", y="A",hue="Name")
```

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html